# Struggling with a Sql Server Query - Joins

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to build a query which pulls data from 3 tables and fills the table  called #TempStudentAcademics that is visible in the screenshot below:

[image]

I am just not getting the query structure right and running into an error, now this may be due to my lack of experience with join but I try none the less.

The tables I need to pull the data from are:

**STUDENTS**

[image]

**TESTS**

[image]

**STUDENT_SCORES**

[image]

I have tried multiple scenerio's , but I'm struggling most with taking the row data of the results for each student  for the respective test and entering it into a now individual test column.

Below is one of the many variations I tried and failed:

```
  SELECT STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID, isnull(STUDENTS.STUDENT_FIRSTNAME,'') +' '+ isnull(STUDENTS.STUDENT_SURNAME,''), STUDENT_SCORES.STUDENT_SCORE , AVG(STUDENT_SCORES.STUDENT_SCORE) FROM 
        (select * from STUDENT_SCORES) STUDENT_SCORES
        inner join
        (select * from TESTS)TESTS
        on STUDENT_SCORES.TEST_ID=TESTS.TEST_ID
        inner join
        (select * from SUBJECTS) SUBJECTS
        on TESTS.SUBJECT_ID= SUBJECTS.SUBJECT_ID
        inner join
        (Select * from STUDENTS) STUDENTS
        on STUDENT_SCORES.STUDENT_ID=STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID
```

Comment: Two things, first this looks a LOT like homework and people will help with homework but not do it for you. Also, images of tables and data are nearly worthless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I would ask why are you joining to subqueries instead of the tables? That is doing nothing but making this more complicated than it needs to be. And when you get an error you should share the error message, just saying you got an error is not helpful.

Comment: @SeanLange. 
Thanks for the comment, But just to carify - The screenshots are to show the Tbl data. This also isnt homework , Its a project I am working on my own to advnace my sql server knowledge. Getting someone to do it for me is not trying at all. 
I can post all the variations i spent time trying , but I thought 1 failed attempt would be sufficient

Comment: Well...it is a failed atttempt but we don't know what error message you are getting. And if you don't want someone to post an answer what do you want as a response? I would suggest starting by getting rid of the subqueries. Just join to the table.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use GroupBy to easily get the test total and average of each test. however the student_total_average is a little tricky. how do you want to calculate that column?

Comment: I was going to try do an AVG() all the scores under the same Student ID.
Not sure if thats the best way to do it

Comment: yea that would get you the math_avg, English_avg, and science_avg. I don't know what did you want to do with student_total_average.

Comment: ohhhh I just saw the STUDENT_SCORE_AVERAGE column in your Students table. maybe the student_total_average is an average of that column? if so, just run the AVG() function on that column and you should be okay. Let me know if you need me to write the script but you can start with what others said. Get away from sub queries and use join only. then you can use group by to run the avg() function.